# Origin of “I'm an idiot. Comes from upbringing. My father was an idiot. My mother was an idiot”

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

> I'm an idiot. Comes from upbringing.
>
> My father was an idiot. My
> mother was an idiot too.

I've traversed all the Monty Python I know. Maybe something French?

I've used this 100+ times for comedic effect. Is it original?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=AJDxLx5RRYUC&pg=PA263&dq=%22My+father+was+an+idiot%22+My+mother+was+an+idiot+too.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDlP7G_6rrAhU7CTQIHYnICz4Q6AEwAXoECAMQAg

Comment: @HotLicks  My wording is jocular by design. The patriarchy angle is unhelpful to my question unless in the form of an answer.

Comment: @HotLicks (Hite report: <g>)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 1985 movie *Back To The Future* there is [a scene](https://youtu.be/yau7Z3vMBo0) with the following dialogue:

> Stella Baines: He's a very strange young man.
>
> Sam Baines: He's an idiot. Comes from upbringing. Parents are probably idiots too. Lorraine, if you ever have a kid that acts that way I'll disown you.

The "idiot" Sam is talking about actually *is* his daughter Lorraine's future son Marty, but of course they don't know that, they don't know about the time travel involved.

It's not exactly the wording you used, but it's very similar, and given in your version you're talking about yourself obviously you would not say that your parents were "probably" idiots, you would put it more definitely because you know your parents.

I'm not claiming that *Back To The Future* had the first ever use of the concept, it's just the first documented example that i could think of.

Comment: Certainly this general concept has been expressed numerous times.

Comment: @HotLicks - Agreed. I've added a note to my answer to make it clear I'm not claiming that the idea originated with the movie, it's just the first documented example I thought of. Incidentally, are you a musician? Where does your user name come from?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not curious about the sentiment, I'm curious about the phrasing.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Use Google with quotation marks.